# ABAP: How to write every row of a table into an excel file

Tags: excel, abap

I wanted to loop through a table and write each row of data from the table into an excel document.

```
LOOP AT IT_Table INTO ST_Table.    
   IF IT_Table[] IS NOT INITIAL.      
         DELETE FROM ZLN.
         MOVE-CORRESPONDING IT_Table[] TO IT_ZLN[].
         MODIFY ZLN FROM TABLE IT_ZLN. 

         "Code here to write to excel
       ENDIF.
ENDLOOP.
```

Comment: Are you going to email it, or download to a local directory?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because the code supplied does not make sense (checking whether a table is empty inside the loop???) and does not show any attempt of the user to tacke the actual problem.

Comment: @vwegert : agree with you. Also too mamy  possibilities with too few informations.

Answer (score 0):

FM GUI_DOWNLOAD - first header, then append line.

```
CALL FUNCTION 'GUI_DOWNLOAD'
    EXPORTING
      filename              = "C:\myexcel.xls"
    TABLES
      data_tab              = lt_hdr.


LOOP AT it_table INTO st_table.
... "here your code 

APPEND st_table to it_output.
CALL FUNCTION 'GUI_DOWNLOAD'
    EXPORTING
      filename = "C:\myexcel.xls"
      append   = 'X' "this will append line to your file
    TABLES
      data_tab = it_output. "table with one record wich you should collect
CLEAR it_output.
ENDLOOP.
```

SAP_CONVERT_TO_XLS_FORMAT can read about this FM